# DotNetZip Passwords Not Working or Incorrect

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, dotnetzip

I have an ADF that generates files and then Zips them to a container. After that's completed, I call an Azure Function that reads the Zip file and adds passwords. From the documentation, the password is applied to the individual entries in the archive. I iterate through the entries in the Azure Function and add the passwords and then upload that zip file back to the same container OVERWRITING the orginal one. However, when I unzip the file (using 7zip) the passwords I added doesn't work and says it's wrong.

Here's the block of code:

```
string zipName = objParam.ZipFileName;
                Logger.LogInformation("Starting Password Protect of Zip File");
                var blobClient = BlobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(objParam.DestinationContainer).GetBlobClient(zipName);

                Logger.LogInformation("Zip File Name: " + objParam.ZipFileName)  
using (Stream zipStream = await blobClient.OpenReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Read(zipStream);    
                    zipFile.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.None;
                    zipFile.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;

                    foreach (var entry in zipFile)
                    {                        
                        entry.Password = "Test123";
                    }

                    var zipOutputStream = new MemoryStream();
                    zipFile.Save(zipOutputStream);
                    zipOutputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    zipStream.Close();
                    await blobClient.UploadAsync(zipOutputStream, true);
                    zipOutputStream.Close();
                }
```

Password protect a zip file using DotNetZip library.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code a bit and it worked for me.

```
     string zipName = "Files.zip";
     log.LogInformation("Starting Password Protect of Zip File");

      BlobServiceClient blob_SrvcClnt = new BlobServiceClient("Connection_String");
      BlobContainerClient cntrClnt = blob_SrvcClnt.GetBlobContainerClient("mycntr444");
      BlobClient blbClient = cntrClnt.GetBlobClient(zipName);

      log.LogInformation("Zip File Name: " + zipName);
       using (Stream zipStream = await blbClient.OpenReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
         {
                ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Read(zipStream);
                zipFile.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.None;
                zipFile.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;

                foreach (var entry in zipFile)
                {
                    entry.Password = "Test123";
                }

                var zipOutputStream = new MemoryStream();
                zipFile.Save(zipOutputStream);
                zipOutputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                zipStream.Close();
                await blbClient.UploadAsync(zipOutputStream, true);
                zipOutputStream.Close();
        }
       log.LogInformation("Password Protect of Zip Files is successfully done.");
```

And installed the below NuGets.

[image]

Uploaded to azure.

[image]

using code able to encrypt the files.

[image]

[image]

After download prompting for the password to open the file.
[image]

Comment: Do the password work? This is my issue, the password isn't working.

Comment: Yes, it  worked for me. And I shared the code, check from your end once.

Comment: Able to open the file and able to see the content after entering the password which is used in the code.